# calculating empirical distribution of dataset in oracle using model clause

Tags: oracle, model

I can find empirical distribution that way

```
    select command_type, duration, round(percentage, 2)
    from (select distinct command_type,duration_sec,
                        percent_rank() over(partition by command_type order by duration) percentage
          from command_durations
          order by 1, 2)
```

The question is how to do the same using oracle model clause. I have started with this

```
select command_type,duration,dur_count from command_durations
model UNIQUE SINGLE REFERENCE
partition by (command_type)
dimension by ( duration)
measures(0 dur_count)
rules(
dur_count[duration]=count(1)[cv(duration)]
)
order by command_type,duration
```

But now I need to make records distinct, in order to be able to proceed with finding empirical distribution.

How to do the records distinct in the model clause?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take that query and use 'distinct' on it, one method might be to wrap that in a From Subquery statement, and then do a distinct.  For instance:

```
Select Distinct command_type, duration, dur_count
From (
    [Your Code]
)
```

Let me know if that works.